# How does the Lumen/Laravel Logging system work?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm looking into Laravel (and now actually Lumen) and how it works so I set out a little task of modifying the error logger to learn more about the system but I seem to be failing to find where the logging code is stored/written.

So I'm calling a Facade like warning like so:

```
Log::warning('log this error');
```

When calling this static function it seems to be calling:

```
illuminate\support\Facades\Log.php
```

In this file it has a simple function which simply returns a string?

```
protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
{
    return 'log';
}
```

This is where the trail goes cold for me, where is the actual logging code? I can't find where any of the code that is actually writing to the log file.

Comment: The return (`log`) is the name of a key in the _service container_. So whatever is bound to `log` is where the “logging code” is. Ergo, the _façade_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Larval uses `Monolog`, which can be found in `/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php`. `warning()` calls `addRecord()`, which creates the details for the line and pushes it to the processor to write to the file.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is send an e-mail when an error is logged, where would you suggest is the best place for this? Changing the vendor code doesn't seem the best decision for this.

Comment: Definitely not. You can either create a class that extends the logger, or create a new function that will log the line and also send an email, then use that function instead of `Log`.